# Delphi Grid Visible Item

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-7

HI all,

I am working with Delphi 7. I am facing a problem with Grid.

My Grid having 100 rows, I am appending some more after that. For example, I am selected item  is on 1oth. The grid shows 20 items on screen at a time. I scrolled the grid to downward. I reached last one. Here grid's Itemindex= 10; Please note the selected item is not showing on the visible window. When I adds the item, the grid refresh and moving to show 10th item.

I don't want to do this.

My requirement is When Adding new rows, Screen should remain same, as shown last time.

Expecting quick reply.

Thanks and Regards,

VIJESH V.NAIR
System Analyst.
Delhi, India.

Comment: What is Grid and how do you add items to it?

Comment: Please don't ask for things like 'Expecting quick reply.'. Everybody needs a quick reply. People answering your questions are all volunteering to do this. Don't hury them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now, your question is to vague for me to answer. You should make at least these things clearer: What type of grid to you use (TDBGrid, TStringGrid, ...), how do you add rows, how do you scroll (by code or by hand), how does it look before/after (provide screen shots), what do you mean with screen (the grid itself, or the whole screen).

Comment: I agree with @TOndrej and @Jeroen. You need to specify the type of grid and other information. The correct answer may vary a lot depending on it.

Comment: I think that he means that the cursor should stay on the same row, even though rows are being added at the end.

Comment: @No'am Newman: By "cursor" [as in "mouse cursor", but not "editor caret" or "focused item"], I assume that you mean "focused cell". I also thought so, until I tried this, and saw that this is the default behaviour, that is, there appear not to be any problem.

Comment: Its Resolve by Self with TopRow property

Answer (score 0):

Before adding an item bookmark the current row of your table that correspond to dbgrid.
Afer adding an item goto your bookmark
a sample for working with TBookmark:
(you can replace clientdataset1 with your tableName like table1)

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DB, DBClient, ExtCtrls, ActnList, Grids, DBGrids,
  DBCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    pnlClient: TPanel;
    pnlBottom: TPanel;
    btnFirst: TButton;
    btnLast: TButton;
    btnNext: TButton;
    btnPrior: TButton;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    btnSetRecNo: TButton;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    btnGetBookmark: TButton;
    btnGotoBookmark: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLastClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSetRecNoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnGetBookmarkClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnGotoBookmarkClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FBookmark: TBookmark;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('C:\Employee.cds');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnFirstClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.First;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Prior;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Next;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnLastClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Last;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnSetRecNoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Value: string;
begin
  Value := '1';
  if InputQuery('RecNo', 'Enter Record Number', Value) then
    ClientDataSet1.RecNo := StrToInt(Value);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnGetBookmarkClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FBookmark) then
    ClientDataSet1.FreeBookmark(FBookmark);

  FBookmark := ClientDataSet1.GetBookmark;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnGotoBookmarkClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FBookmark) then
    ClientDataSet1.GotoBookmark(FBookmark)
  else
    ShowMessage('No bookmark set!');
end;

end.
```